# Python: Functional map() list of dictionaries to list of specified field value

Tags: python-2.7, lambda, functional-programming

Hi given the following java 8 code, how can i do the following in python 2.7

```
listOfNames = modules.map(module -> module.modulename()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Bear in mind as im in python i am iterating over dictionaries so modulename is accessed as module['modulename']

Comment: We aren't code translators

Comment: They speak for plenty of us. Be lazy elsewhere.

Comment: i was not trying to be lazy. i wrote that in java because i knew how. And i thought that someone would understand the semantics, which someone did. If @AndrewL had asked for more clarification i would have given it. p.s i see my comment was deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in Python:

```
[module['modulename'] for module in modules]
```

---

Or, with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
In [1]: modules = [{'module': 'module1'}, {'module': 'module2'}]

In [2]: from operator import itemgetter

In [3]: map(itemgetter('module'), modules)  # on Python3, you would need to call list() on it to see the same result
Out[3]: ['module1', 'module2']
```